# Persistence solution for mobile Phonegap / HTML5 App

Tags: database, json, sqlite, persistence, cordova

I am developing a mobile app for Android and iOS using jQuery Mobile.
The app will be deployed to Android and iOS devices utilizing Phonegap.

My problem is that I need a local offline data storage mostly for read operations.

I am planning to pull a data set from a web server (MySQL/web service) about once a month (whenever there is new data) and store it for local use on the device.

Now the question, what persistence solution should I use?

There is a tool called lawnchair by a member of the Phonegap team. Anyone tried it? What are the pros and cons? http://westcoastlogic.com/lawnchair/

What about sqlite? Is it working across Android and iOS devices?

THX

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You could simply use HTML5 Storage / SQL Lite for this. Take a look at: http://diveintohtml5.ep.io/storage.html

I`ve been using Localstorage on iOs and Android without any problems, and since localstorage is backed up by sqllite i think you should be fine. (but  i can´t say anything for sure for sqllite on android)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. SQLite was not quite suitable for my case. I used json files and processed them with jquery.

Answer (score 0):

HTML5 storage works fine on Android. A nice tool to make reading and writing to the database easier is persistenceJS.

I've just started on setting up the iPhone version of my jQueryMobile / Phonegap app. It stalls right at the point where the first call to localdb is made. This may be a problem of the iOS simulator, since the regular Safari runs my app just fine from the browser.

Answer (score 0):

The HTML5 LocalStorage option will works fine until iOS 5.0. But there might be some problems from iOS 5.1 and later.

So my suggestion is to *write some javascript code to back up to the document folder via fileAPI, and reconstruct the WebSQL database periodically.*